# How do I move the Azure VM Agent WindowsAzure folder to a different drive

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am not sure when the Azure VM Agent got installed on my VM.  I know I didn't manually do it.  Regardless, it created a WindowsAzure folder on my VMs C: drive.  Unfortunately, that drive is not that big so it is eating into valuable storage.  I have an E: drive with tons of space.  How do I get the Azure VM Agent to use the E: drive instead of the C: drive on my VM?

Comment: If the reply is helpful, you could checkmark under "Answer" to close your question. Or let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could not directly move the WindowsAzure folder to another since the Azure VM Agent is installed by default on any Windows VM deployed from an Azure Marketplace image and even you could manually install it, you can not select the folder location.

In this case, you could **expand your OS disk** for more space on your VM c: drive. Note that **The new size should be greater than the existing disk size. The maximum allowed is 2048 GB for OS disks.** You can follow this document to [expand the OS drive of a virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk).

Hope this will help.